# SharpDX Content.Load<Texture2D>

Tags: directx-11, texture2d, sharpdx, dds-format

I just installed SharpDX 2.5.0 into Visual Studio, and now there is one really curios and unexpected errror:

I wanted to start with Atari's 'Pong', so i drew a .bmp file with a ball, convertet it into a .dds file with

> Easy2Convert BMP to DDS

added it to the Content, and tried to load it. So i added this line

> ballTexture = Content.Load("Ball");

but it failed with the message AssetNotFoundException, the same with

> ballTexture = Content.Load("Ball.dds");

and there are hardly no tutorials to find, neither did i find an useful answer...
Thats the full path to this picture:

> H:\Programmieren\Pong\Pong\Content\Ball.dds

Looking forward to your answers, and please excuse my knowlegde, I was used to XNA, and it was much more easier...

Comment: Could it be that you have to specify the folder in which the file is located? e.g.: `Content.Load("Content\Ball.dds");` ? And you could also try to add the full path into the string if that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharpDX.Toolkit content is loaded from a folder relative to the folder where your program is located. Also you should mark the texture with build action `ToolkitTexture` (open file properties in Visual Studio).

After build, the file should be copied to a path like this:

```
H:\Programmieren\Pong\Pong\bin\Debug\Content\Ball.tkb`
```

(the extension may be different - I don't remember exactly).

After this, you can load the asset by calling `ballTexture = Content.Load(@"Content\Ball");`

Alternatively, you can set the root path for content manager during initialization:

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
...
//and load the textures with
ballTexture = Content.Load(@"Ball");
```

All this is demonstrated in SharpDX Toolkit samples (located in `Samples\SharpDXToolkitSamples.sln`).